# SharePoint Store with FBA and SSL

Tags: sharepoint-addin, forms-authentication, ssl

I have a problem in my SharePoint site configured using FBA. 
I can add an app from the SharePoint Store but I cannot use it. The page is entirely empty when I try to access an app from this site.

I also configured SSL in this site. I get a certificate error when I'm trying to access an app, but I don't know if installing a new certificate (*.apps.mydomain.com) will resolve this issue?

I need to be sure that the problem comes from SSL.

Comment: Do you have a wildcard SSL cert for your apps?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that SharePoint Apps don't work OOTB in an FBA or SAML (Trusted Provider) context, cf. http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/12/07/using-sharepoint-apps-with-saml-and-fba-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

You can make them work with the additional piece of code Steve Peschka provides, but since you have no control over the official SharePoint Store, you'll have to set up your own internal SharePoint Store (and build or use open source apps).